# Frequency Count Of Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to know how to determine the frequency count of the *sum:= sum+1* statement in the following program:

```
sum:=0

for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to i do
    for k:=1 to j do
        sum:= sum+1
    end<br/>
  end
end
```

I would also like to know how, in general, to determine the frequency count of all algorithms not just this one specifically.

Comment: Run the program and examine the value of `sum`?

Comment: How is this related to genetic algorithms?

Comment: sorry thought it said generic algorithms... fixed

Comment: Try finding the formula for final value of `sum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**∑∑∑ 1 = ∑∑ j = ∑ (i*(i+1))/2 = ∑(i^2+i)/2 = (n(n+1)(2n+1)/6+n(n+1)/2)/2 = n(n+1)(n+2)/6**

Your formula is this:

```
F(n) = n(n+1)(n+2)/6
```

And currently there is no general way for calculating running times, If there was some way, Complexity theory should be removed from Computer Science.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had figured out the answer already but this is the same exact way I went about it so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For the expression representing the exact frequency, you'll want to consult [summation formulas for polynomials](http://polysum.tripod.com/).

Namely, the inner loops are dependent on the current iteration of the outer loops.  For instance:

```
sum := 0
for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to i do
    sum := sum + 1
```

With respect to `n`, the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+...+n.  In summation notation, it is Σ <sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup> i .

Comment: If, for example, n was 200, what would the frequency count and value of sum be?

Comment: If you want a specific solution, not a general formula, how about just running the program and looking at the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's build this up from the inside out.

The line of code is executed `j` times each time the inner loop is run. So far so good.

So for each time the middle loop is run, we execute the statement `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + i - 1 + i` times. Anyone should recognize that as equal to `i * (i + 1) / 2`. Or `(i^2 + i) / 2`

For each time we run the outer loop, we execute the statement `((1^2+1) + (2^2+2) + ... (n^2+n))/2` times.

I'll leave the final result as an exercise for the reader.

Though this problem is undecidable in general - if you knew how many times each line of code in a program would execute, you would have solved the Halting Problem.